How to do ci-cd of Django DRF application through Github to AWS?
Before deploying my django drf server i need to test it during production phase so i need to host my django drf project in github and so through ci-cd to aws. So is it need to be dockerized before sending it to aws.
So can anyone please shortly explain how to do it. Is there any tutorial or any documentations to read and is there any free tier for hosting it during development phase. I'll be moving to the priced tier after development only.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So I need to know How to deploy django drf project with cicd using github actions into the aws platform?
